# FullCalendar - Show times for every row in agendaDay

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I'm building an web application using AngularUI-calendar that basically uses FullCalendar.js under it.

My problem is that I'm using the agendaDay as my defaultView with slotMinutes setted as 15.

My calendar config is like this:

```
    calendar: {
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        editable: true,
        timeFormat: {
            agenda: 'HH:mm{ - HH:mm}',
        },
        axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
        slotMinutes: 15,
    }
```

Which gives me this look and feel:

http://s30.postimg.org/aqt720mep/full_Calendar_row_without_times.jpg

It looks good but I want to show the times for every row. Something like this:

http://s24.postimg.org/vrvnhv39x/full_Calendar_row_with_times.jpg

I manage how to do it changing the line 3004 on the FullCalendar.js:

**This is the original line**

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat'))  : '&nbsp;') +
```

**This is my modification**

```
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? "< b>" + formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) + "< /b>" : formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat'))) +
```

I was wondering if there's any other way to do this because I was trying to avoid to do any change on the FullCalendar source code. I don't want to create a branch just for this modification. Is there a way to configure this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that this is a bug on the FullCalendar.js. You you select the slotMinutes as 15, 30 or 45. You got this bug of empty lines on your agendaView.

The issue can be seen here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=946&colspec=ID

A fix for this issue will be quite easy. The problem is on the code below:

```
"<th class='fc-agenda-axis " + headerClass + "'>" +
((!slotNormal || !minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) : '&nbsp;') +
"</th>"
```

If you want to show only the hour marks (1pm, 2pm , 3pm, etc), change the code to:

```
"<th class='fc-agenda-axis " + headerClass + "'>" +
((!minutes) ? formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) : '&nbsp;') +
"</th>"
```

If you want to always show the time:

```
"<th class='fc-agenda-axis " + headerClass + "'>" +
formatDate(d, opt('axisFormat')) +
"</th>"
```

The variable slotNormal is causing the problem. The variable is basically a mod 15 with the value that you put into slotMinutes on your calendar config. So, it will fail the condition in the original code for the values 15, 30 and 45 (or any other multiple).

Regards,

Pedro Vaz

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 events that you can implement(any one of them) in your js and change the rendering. But never tried what you want. you can check the methods eventRender or eventAfterAllRender. You might give them a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked this two events before. As far as I understood (I don't know if I'm wrong), these two methods are used to the event template and not the row template. \n
The only place I found where I could change the time in each row was on the axisFormat (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/axisFormat/).\n
the documentation says: "The default value will produce times that look like "5pm" and "5:30pm".\n
Since it says "5:30pm", it made me wonder if there's any other solution than the one I found. Because with the original code, the "5:30pm" will never be shown